# Triggering mousedown/touch and drag and release events in Fabric.js remotely

Tags: fabricjs

Using Fabric.js, is it possible to trigger the "mousedown", "move", and "mouseup" events from outside the canvas, e.g. with jQuery ui slider control?

I can't see any way to get a reference to each object so as to trigger events on it from outside canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just didn't see this example for how to access the objects:

http://fabricjs.com/controls/

This does what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why you want to trigger events from outside?
With the following function calls you can get access to objects:

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
var activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
var object1 = canvas.item(0); // item(1) ...

canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {
  //iterate over all existing objects
});

var objects = canvas.getObjects(); // returns array of all objects
```

Comment: It would allow me to manipulate objects in a shared environment with 2 devices operating similar screens with websockets connecting actions between users.